# Not able find method probablePrime() in scala doc for BigInt class

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I am quite new in Scala, I was searching probablePrime() method in scala doc of BIgInt class . But i could not see the method . While i checked the github coce for the BigInt.scala , there i found it is present.

Can any body make me understand why the method is not present in scala doc.

Thanks!!

Comment: It's a method of the companion object of `BigInt`, so you should switch to companion object scaladoc to see it: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.7/index.html#scala.math.BigInt$@probablePrime%28bitLength:Int,rnd:scala.util.Random%29:scala.math.BigInt

Comment: Thank you Kolmar , I knew that BigInt has a companion object, but it did not strike into my head .